# double quotes in returned json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have an action returning a simple JSON. For demonstration purposes, I will paste the sample code. Simple class to serialize:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

The action which returns the json:

```
public JsonResult Test()
{
    var employee = new Employee { FullName = "Homer Simpson" };
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(employee);

    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is where I am confused. When I call this action from  the browser and look at the response with Fiddler, this is the result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Mon, 15 Aug 2011 20:52:34 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 34
Connection: Close

"{\"FullName\":\"Homer Simpson\"}"
```

The "JSON" tab in Fiddler reads "The selected-response does not contain valid JSON text". 
The valid response should be like this:

```
"{"FullName":"Homer Simpson"}"
```

What is going on here?
Thanks

Comment: `"{\"FullName\":\"Homer Simpson\"}"` is the escaped version of the stringed JSON object.  When it is parsed, the engine will turn it into `{ "FullName":"Home Simpson" }`.  Because it is surrounded in quotes outside of the curly braces, the internal quotes must be escaped or you will have an invalid string.

Comment: I understand that but shouldn't fiddler parse the returned string into JSON object and show the JSON in the JSON tab?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to serialize into JSON yourself, this should do:

```
public JsonResult Test() {
  var employee = new Employee { FullName = "Homer Simpson" };
  return Json(employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Your code effectively serializes it twice, which gives you a string result.

The valid response should actually be this:

```
{"FullName":"Homer Simpson"}
```

(without the surrounding quotes)

Answer (score 0):

I got on this issue because another error, it could be useful for someone:
Just using serialize, using in Model property i was getting the line below.

My serialize line return of my class  `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(playlists)` --> server side

My Js line gettin serialized `var JsonString = '@Model.PlaylistModelList'` 

Output: `'[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Bastard_01.mp4&quot;,&quot;duration&quot;...}]`

My corret Js Line: `var JsonStrin2 = '@Html.Raw(Model.PlaylistModelList)'`

 Output: `'[{"name":"Bastard_01.mp4","duration":45..."}]`