# ASP.Net Core controller actions produces content type text/plain for simple strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have the following controller and action.

```
[Route("/api/simple")]
public class SimpleController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("test")]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

When I call it, I expect action to return `"test"` (which is valid JSON), but instead it returns `test` (without quotation marks) is this a valid behavior, or bug? Am I missing something?

```
GET http://localhost:5793/api/simple/test HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:5793
Accept: application/json


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 09 Aug 2015 14:37:45 GMT
Content-Length: 4

test
```

Note: For ASP.NET Core 2.0+ this doesn't apply when an Accept header is present in the request - but it still applies if the accept header is omitted and content negotiation occurs.

Comment: This is valid behavior if you actually want it to return the quotes use the escape sequence: return "\"Test\"";

Comment: @BryanMudge But, I'm expecting a json output. 'test' is not a valid JSON, for example, if I return an object, it serializes the object.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070759/double-quotes-in-returned-json

Comment: Problem there is double-serialization of the object. But in this case, it doesn't serialize at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @mbudnik pointed out, the culprit here is *StringOutputFormatter*, which somehow gets selected to format the output instead of *JsonOutputFormatter*. His code snippet, however, no longer works because there’s been some changes to ASP.NET Core since then. Use this instead:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;

public class Startup {

    // ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        // Add MVC, altering the default output formatters so that JsonOutputFormatter is preferred over StringOutputFormatter
        services.AddMvc(options => {
            var stringFormatter = options.OutputFormatters.OfType<StringOutputFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (stringFormatter != null) {
                options.OutputFormatters.Remove(stringFormatter);
                options.OutputFormatters.Add(stringFormatter);
            }
        });
    }

    // ...

}
```

Or, if you think you don't need *StringOutputFormatter* at all, you can remove it altogether:

```cs
services.AddMvc(options => {
    options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>();
});
```

IMO this should be considered a bug, since you asked for a JSON response (`Accept: application/json`) and returning the string without quotes is definitely **not** JSON. However, [the official position is that this is expected](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2944).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the *StringOutputFormatter* is getting into your way.
If you remove it or move it after the *JsonOutputFormatter* you will get the desired results.

[image: Output formatters]