# Web API returns escaped JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a POST method in a .NET core 2.0 web API project that needs to return a JSON (using newtonsoft). I have the following code at the end of the method:

```
ObjectResult objRes = new ObjectResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, settings));
objRes.ContentTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
return objRes
```

When I test this using Postman I get a result like:

```
"{\"name\":\"test\",\"value\":\"test\"}"
```

As you can see, the JSON is still escaped in postman. When I test the exact same code in a .NET core 1.0 project, I get the following in Postman:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "value": "test"
}
```

How can I get the same result in my .NET core 2.0 project?
I was thinking it might have been due to Newtonsoft but when I debug the deserialization into a string, the debugger shows exactly the same (escaped) value in both the .NET core 1.0 and 2.0 project.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42214435/4137916) (not the same framework, but the issue may be along the same lines).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrated web service to .NET Core 2.0 and returning json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785619/migrated-web-service-to-net-core-2-0-and-returning-json)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just return result in the controller and it will be serialized by the framework.

```
[HttpPost]
public object Post()
{
    var result = new MyObject { Name = "test", Value = "test" };
    return result;
}
```

Or you can do:

```
return new OkObjectResult(result);
```

Or if you inherit from Controller:

```
return Ok(result);
```

Comment: Yes, however JSON.NET does have a couple of advantages over the .NET serializer, so see the solution stackoverflow.com/a/48335234/1317161 to make it work with JSON.NET

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you have to serialize your object before sending it. In .NET Core it will be serialized for you by default.

Comment: Yes, however JSON.NET does have a couple of advantages over the .NET serializer, so see the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48335234/1317161 to make it work with JSON.NET